# Does anyone know what, if any, doc generator was used for techbase.kde.org?

Tags: documentation-generation, kde-plasma, code-documentation, xml-documentation

I was looking over some of the API reference pages for KDE and was specifically looking into their techcase docs and the more I navigate through the sub-pages of https://techbase.kde.org, the more I really enjoy their readability, lean, clean, etc. design.

Does anyone know what, if any, doc generator was used for techbase.kde.org?

Comment: A quick look at the html code of the homepage reveals a tag `<meta name="generator" content="MediaWiki 1.20.2" />`. Or did you mean the pages at http://api.kde.org/? In this case, you can see Doxygen stylesheets.

Comment: @Riccardo - Actually I was thinking of both. I did think that api.kde.org was created using Doxygen and was wondering about the techbase one, but you've confirmed that, thanks!

Comment: I'll turn my comment into an answer then, you're welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look at the html code of the homepage reveals a [MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) tag:

```
<meta name="generator" content="MediaWiki 1.20.2" />`
```

The pages at http://api.kde.org instead expose, among some others, a [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) stylesheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="attica/html/doxygen.css" />
```